# JSON ASP.NET Deserialization failing, getting null

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

From Javascript I send my object via string like so, data is what facebook FQL query returns:

```
var propData = new Object();
propData.d = data;
var jString = JSON.stringify(propData);
$('#<%=Hidden1.ClientID%>').val(jString);
$('#UpdatePanelTrigger').click();
```

Then, I receive this string on server side, display this JSON string in a label (which looks ok to me) and try to Deserialize it, code below.

```
 public class Friends
{
    public IList<Dictionary<string,string>> data {get; set;}
}

protected void UpdateTrigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JSON_out.Text = Hidden1.Value;
    Friends fbookFriends = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptDerializer().Deserialize<Friends>(JSON_out.Text);
    obj_check.Text = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSErializer().Serialize(fbookFriends);
    //The result of above line is {"data":null}
}
```

I don't understand why Deserializer refuses to convert this string to JSON.
Any help, would be greatly appreciated.
I.N.

PS: If it helps, My JSON string received on server, looks like this: 
{"d":[{"uid":"XXXXXXXX","name":"Bro Number1","pic_square":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/beautiful_avatar.jpg"},{"uid":"XXXXX2","name":...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to deserialize your json string in question your `Friends` class should be something like that

```
public class Friend
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string pic_square { get; set; }
}

public class Friends
{
    public List<Friend> d { get; set; }
}
```

But your comments says you have some top level fields like `data` (`//The result of above line is {"data":null}`)

Comment: Wow, the fix was as simple as changing "data" to "d"... Thank you very much sir!

Comment: It's not a direct answer but I'd recommend you to use JSON.NET for all JSON code http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx